# using split_part() in function

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I am fairly new to functions and I'm trying to build a function that will take a value from one column of the row being inserted, do some string manipulation, then insert the result into another column before inserting/updating.

Here is the table structure:

colA | colB | colC | colD

I tested the following select query on the values in colB and it returns what I want it to:

```
select split_part(split_part(colB, '/', 6), '.', 1) from my_table;
```

The type of colB is varchar and I want the result of the above query to be inserted into colC (which is bigint) before inserting/updating any row.

Here is how far I got with my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_object_date() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW."colC" := (split_part(split_part("colB", '/', 6), '.', 1));
  RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "build_object_date" BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "my_table" EXECUTE PROCEDURE build_object_date();
```

This is the error I get when trying to insert a new row:

> [42703] ERROR: column "colB" does not exist Where: PL/pgSQL function
>   build_object_date() line 3 at assignment

I'm a little bit lost of why this is failing. Can someone point in the right direction?

Comment: Use `new."colB"`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I actually had it like that before, but that gave me a different error: ```[55000] ERROR: record "new" is not assigned yet Detail: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate. Where: PL/pgSQL function build_object_date() line 3 at assignment```

Comment: I found the solution. You were partially correct @a_horse_with_no_name that I needed new."colB" but I also needed to add "FOR EACH ROW" to my trigger.